# Resubmitting File in FileField after Validation Error in Django

Tags: django, django-models

In Django project forms with FileField, ImageField. Everything works great, but when ValidationError is raised, I have to reselect all files and images again. I want to avoid this one by caches concept in django 
but I am not getting currect output please correct this code and add if any required

-models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import ImageField
# or if you use sorl-thumbnail
# from sorl.thumbnail.fields import ImageField

import os

def resume_path(instance, filename):
    fn, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return "resumes/{id}{ext}".format(id=instance.title, ext=ext)

class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    image =  ImageField(upload_to=resume_path)
```

-admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
# Register your models here.
from django.contrib import admin
from file_resubmit.admin import AdminResubmitMixin
from .models import Page

from django.forms import ModelForm
from file_resubmit.admin import AdminResubmitImageWidget, 

AdminResubmitFileWidget
from .models import Page

class PageModelForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
         model = Page
         widgets = {
             'picture': AdminResubmitImageWidget,
             'file': AdminResubmitFileWidget,
         }
         fields = '__all__'

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin,AdminResubmitMixin):
    form = PageModelForm

admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

-settings.py

```
    CACHES = {
             'default': {
                 'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
             },
             "file_resubmit": {
                 'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
                  "LOCATION": '/home/xxxxxx/Downloads/Python/Projects_Python/pleasecome/tmp/file_resubmit',
                # "LOCATION": os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'tmp/file_resubmit/'),
             },
    }

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sub',
    'file_resubmit',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: What's you question? [ask]

Comment: How to avoid reselect the file or image if validation error raised after submission(SAVE) of model Form in django

Comment: You already use [django-file-resubmit](https://github.com/un1t/django-file-resubmit). What is not working as expected? You seem to have followed the setup guide, but changed the order of parent class inheritance here: `class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, AdminResubmitMixin):` The order of mixins can be significant. Since you are using a custom form, you might not need to add the mixin.

Comment: There's some other issues with your code. You have duplicate imports, and the indentation of `class Meta:` is incorrect syntax.

Comment: Thank u Very much  Heken Lid it is Working!!!!!!!!

Comment: Good. I've submitted an answer as well. If it solved your problem you can mark that that answer as accepted to show that this question has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the class `PageAdmin`

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin,AdminResubmitMixin):
    form = PageModelForm
```

According to the documentation for [django-form-resubmit](https://github.com/un1t/django-file-resubmit) the ModelAdmin should be be created in one of these ways:

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PageModelForm

class PageAdmin(AdminResubmitMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

The order you declare parent classes is significant, so you should follow the official example. And since you have a custom form, you don't need to use the `AdminResubmitMixin` at all.